# AngularJs Table Sorting when Data is nested

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

How can I approach table sorting in angularjs, when my data is nested and not all columns are first level citizens of the objects.

**Data (excerpt)**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Team A",
        "categories": [
            {
                "label": "FG%",
                "value": 4676,
                "points": 7
            },
            {
                "label": "FT%",
                "value": 8387,
                "points": 9
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "Team B",
        "categories": [
            {
                "label": "FG%",
                "value": 5285,
                "points": 10
            },
            {
                "label": "FT%",
                "value": 6111,
                "points": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng:click="changeSorting('name')">Name</th>
                <th ng:click="changeSorting('name')">Points</th>
                <th ng:click="changeSorting(value.label)" ng-repeat="(index, value) in data.teams[0].categories">{{value.label}}</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="team in data.teams | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending ">
                <td>{{team.name}}</td>
                <td>{{team.totalPoints}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="(name, cat) in team.categories">
                    {{cat.value}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is a approach I found a few times. Anyway, because of the structure of my data, I am afraid this isn't the right idea.

**Sorting on Controller**

```
$scope.sort = {
    column: 'name',
    descending: false
};

$scope.changeSorting = function(column) {
    var sort = $scope.sort;
    if (sort.column == column) {
        sort.descending = !sort.descending;
    } else {
        sort.column = column;
        sort.descending = false;
    }
};
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SunnyRed/mTywq/2/

Comment: Where is the table sorting? Also, have you looked at [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) as a ready-made-solution?

Comment: There was none, because I don't know of any approach. I still have added a common way for table-sorting, but that only works for the first level citizens. I did have a look at ng-grid, but I had the impression, that nested data isn't featured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your code based on angular documentation at  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng:click="predicate = 'name'; reverse = !reverse">Name</th>
                <th ng:click="predicate = 'totalPoints'; reverse = !reverse">Points</th>
                <th ng:click="toggleSort($index)" ng-repeat="category in data.teams[0].categories">{{category.label}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="team in data.teams | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
                <td>{{team.name}}</td>
                <td>{{team.totalPoints}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="(name, cat) in team.categories">
                    {{cat.value}}
                </td>                    
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Sorting parts**

```
$scope.toggleSort = function(index){
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    $scope.predicate = function(team){
        return team.categories[index].points;
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgalela/Br5Wb/14/

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly, what I was looking for. I've also added a variable on the scope, to remember sorting and so reverse sorting only when the same header is clicked again and otherwise set the default. Nevertheless, many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to lookup the correct category based on it's `label` and then sort using it's associated `value` I'd create a custom `orderBy` function.

To use new function `sortFunc` we add it here:

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in data.teams | orderBy: sortFunc ">
```

Then let the user pick options:

```
<select ng-model="sortVal">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="points">points</option>
    <option value="3PM">3PM</option>
    <option value="PTS">PTS</option>
 </select>
```

Finally here's the sort function which pulls in the chosen option using `$scope.sortVal` and returns the appropriate value for `orderBy` to sort.

```
$scope.sortFunc = function(val) {
    if ($scope.sortVal == 'name') {
         return(val.name);
     } else if ($scope.sortVal == 'points') {
         return(val.totalPoints);
     } else if ($scope.sortVal == '3PM' ||
                $scope.sortVal == 'PTS')  {  
         for (var i = 0; i < val.categories.length; i++) {
            category = val.categories[i];
            if (category.label == $scope.sortVal){
               return(category.value);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Here's the fiddle of this working:  http://jsfiddle.net/mTywq/4/